Why are my photos not being imported from the iphone to macOS?
From this screenshot: in particular - what does that exclamation point on the iCloud icon  for my iphone ("StephenBoesch (2)") mean?

I was able to import onto this mac a couple of days ago and have not changed any settings in the meantime.

Do you have iCloud Photos enabled on the phone?

Yes, but I had had them enabled already and they had been importing. It just stopped. Confusing..

If you have optimize storage on it won’t show photos that aren’t downloaded.

The importing started working again - with no changes to any settings. This seems like an unanswerable situation.
